# How to convert Image to String and vice versa in java

Tags: java

How to convert Image to String and vice versa in java.
I convert a file.jpg to byte array and then convert byte array to String, but when I reconvert the result String to Image, I got error
Here is code

```
public void StringToFile( String s1, String filename ) {
            byte[] byte02 = s1.getBytes( );
            //byte[] byte02 = s1.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            try {
                System.out.println( "Data is corrupted when converting image "
                        +   "file to String and vice versa, this function is just a test" );
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( filename );
                output.write( byte02 );
                output.close();
                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream( byte02 );
                BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read( bis );
                ImageIO.write( bImage2, "jpg", new File( filename ) );
            }
            catch ( Exception ex ) {
                System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please also show the code how you create the `String` from file.jpg! It is possible that the damage has already be done before calling `StringToFile`, most likely at the moment you are creating a `String` from a byte array. `String` is not meant to contain arbitrary binary data, so there are a lot of traps if you try to do it anyway. Usually its the best course of action to stick with byte arrays for binary data.

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can cause problems when you convert binary data into an regular string.

The reason is that converting a byte array into an String converts the bytes into characters using the character encoding of the system. Bytes that have no character mapped to it will be lost or modified in the process.

Instead I'd suggest you use

```
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byte[])
```

to convert the file's bytes into a string value and

```
java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(String)
```

to get the value back into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, avoid converting binary data like a graphics file to `String`. `String` is meant to contain a sequence of Unicode characters, and not arbitrary data. If you need to transform binary data into printable characters, use the approach given in the [the answer by Roland Kreuzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681964/3025453), namely an encoding like base 64.

On Android, to convert a `Bitmap` to `byte[]`, you can use the `Bitmap.compress` method:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

private byte[] getBytesFromImage (Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

This method returns a byte[] array which you can use to store the image in your Database, for instance, as a Blob value.

To convert the byte[] to an Image, use the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArrray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length); // imageBytes is the byte[] array of the image that was returned by the getBytesFromImage method.
```